# How to hide dynamic filter from embedded report in power Bi

Tags: powerbi

I have embedded power Bi report in asp.net mvc application. I have added dynamic filter but how to hide this dynamic filter from filter pane?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can't hide them.